# Passing continuous streaming binary data between two applications

Tags: android, stream, binary, android-contentprovider

I am looking into the problem of continuously distributing binary-data messages from an android service onto other listening applications. I am thinking a publish-subscribe model with a filter of some kind to accomplish the data transfer.

I have tested using intents and broadcast receivers to deliver the messages, but it seems this solution is too slow (Intent-messages with a 32 byte parcelable payload @250Hz distributed to multiple recipients), so I need another more low-level approach instead.

What I had in mind was a way for the subscriber to connect to an outputstream from the publishing service, and have the subscriber open the outputstream as an inputstream and consume the data from it directly.

My problem is now: How do I make an output datastream accessible to another application? Can I use a content-provider? It seems you can do this for an image file or such, but can I make it for a continuous dataflow as well? Otherwise, how can I make the stream accessible outwards using some other datasharing mechanism?

Comment: I'm faced to a similar problem. One way is to use an "internet" socket and it should be fast enough.
But this solutions is more a "hack" than a real one.